# how can i record a song which is playing with AVPlayer and an wav file at a same time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avplayer, avaudiorecorder

I'm developing an App in which i have to record a song and a wav file at a same time.I'm playing song from iPod Music libraries and on a view controller i have placed a button on click of which an wav file starts but when i start recording using AVAudioRecorder,my wav file stop working.
This is my ipod music library's code:-

```
- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) collection 

{
MPMediaItem *item = [[collection items] objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];


// Play the item using AVPlayer


AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];
player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[player play];  
}
```

and this is my code by which i m playing wav file:-

```
-(void)playAudio:(NSString *)path
{
SystemSoundID soundIDWav;
NSString *sound = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"/wavFile.wav"];
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)filePath, &soundIDWav);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundIDWav);
}
```

I'm recording these two by AVAudioRecorder...
Please help.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create audiosession

```
audioSession.delegate = self;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Now play your file in AVAudioPlayer  and at same time start recording using AVAudioRecorder